# The best way to create the class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

The problem is the following: A race has participants and the race has a starting line ordered by a number assigned to the participants. Each participant can use a vehicle and need to registry the information of the vehicles. So the information are: Race: name, location, time, ... Car: race start number, year of manufacture, model, ... Bike: race start number, model, wheel size, ... Horse carriage: race start number, number of horses, ...

What would be the best way to create the class diagram and get the starting line with the vehicles ordered by the race start number?

Case A: raceStartNumber are distributed in different Entities. It would be necessary to do a mapping by raceStartNumber and order the elements obtained.
[image]

Case B: All the vehicles would be ordered on the starting line, but the vehicle class would always have two associations such as null.
[image]

So, which case do you think is better? Would there be any other way to do it?

Comment: I think you're going to have to re-read the chapter about inheritance.

Comment: This. And read about association classes as well as this is clearly something your teacher wants from you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is never a *best* solution. You always have tradeoffs, just that some might be less significant.

Your 2nd example is just wrong in that you use composite aggregation rather than generalization. You would need an open triangle instead of the diamond and omit the multplicities.

Regarding the options you should study [Composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

As noted by @Ister your first approach has also a major flaw. This is that the `raceStartNumber` is an individual property of each vehicle. And there's nothing that constraints them to be unique.

Generally you will not model these `id` properties unless you have some requirement. The *id* of objects is implicit (in programming languages it's usually the memory address of the instance).

I will not go into more details since this site is not meant for reviews.

Comment: I would add that the first solution is also a poor design at best and does not fulfill the described requirements.

Comment: I added a few more comments. One gets seduced to go in more details, but this site isn't meant for code reviews. So I'll leave it as it is.

Comment: Yeah. There should be an easy way to convert a question into a new forum thread.

Comment: If we seek perfection only in the class diagram we will have a lot of work when implementing our controllers. Therefore. Based on the ideas of both diagrams (even if they have errors) Case A is complicated since it does not give us the starting line (with use a query), we would have to create it. Case B is created for the same thing. If we use generalization, we will have the same problem as at the beginning, we do not have the starting line with a query. In Case B, we have the starting line but we have to check what association the data has. I don't know if I'm right or they understand me.

Comment: @Philips Honestly, I don't fully understand your comment. But it seems you got the point that you have to work on your models either way :-)